# php jquery ajax form submitted twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

i had a form which uses jquery validation engine and ajax. and i'm using zend as the framework. but i had this weird case. from my test, i know that there are 3 cases which two of them are correct.
1. when i press enter after i fill out all of the input form, the form submitted normally (once)
2. when i'm in the last input box then i press tab to jump to the submit button and either press enter or click it, the form also submitted normally (once)
3. but after i fill out all of the form, then fill the captcha input box (the cursor is still in the captcha input box) and click the submit button straight out without move the cursor position to other element, then the form submitted twice

i don't understand why this happens. please help me to figure this out.
here is my html code from the :

```
<form id="kk_da" /> 
-- my form --
//here is the captcha
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="mkk_form_captcha">
            <span><strong>security code</strong>*</span>
            <p>
                <img src="<?php print $this->app->base_url ?>lib/captcha.php" id="captcha">
                <br/><a href="#" onclick="" id="change-image"></a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src='<?php print $this->app->base_url ?>lib/captcha.php?'+Math.random();
                return false" id="change-image">Not readable? Change text.</a>
            </p>
            <div class="mkk_field mkk_field_important <?php print $_cap ? 'mkk_field_alert' : ''; ?>
                <?php if($this->error_captcha)print 'alert_captcha'; ?>">
                <?php //print $this->form->getElement('captcha'); ?>
    //the part above is described as follow
    //and it happens that the ajax[ajaxCaptchaCall] is the problem
    <input type="text" size="40" name="captcha" id="captcha" 
class="validate[required,ajax[ajaxCaptchaCall]]" data-prompt-position="bottomRight"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="mkk_cart_buttons">
            <input class="btn btn_blue" name="submit" type="submit" value="Buy" />
            <input type="hidden" name="process_marker" value="process_order" />
            <a href="<?php print $this->app->base_url ?>katalog/form" class="btn">back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is the javascript

```
> jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery("#kk_da").validationEngine('attach',
    {
        onValidationComplete: function(form, status)
        {
            if (status == true)
            {
                var formData = jQuery('#kk_da').serialize();
                jQuery.ajax(
                {
                    url : '<?php print $this->app->base_url ?>katalog/checkout_process',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data :  formData,
                    beforeSend : function()
                    {
                        loading_pop();
                    }
                }).done(function(data)
                {
                    loading_done();

                    if (data== 'success')
                    {
                        window.location = '<?php print $this->app->base_url ?>katalog/success';
                    }
                }).fail(function()
                {
                    loading_done();
                }) ;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**
it seems that i got the problem. it appears that the "ajax[ajaxCaptchaCall]" part is where the problem commence. when i erase that part, my form submitted normally. but then it makes my captcha doesn't work because it bypass it. how can i fix this part so the captcha works and the form submitted only once?

Answer (score 0):

could it be that the attach is executed twice?
jQuery("#kk_da").validationEngine('attach', ....)

OD

try to set form.status = false after serializing it